# org-export-as-latex adds trailing slashes

Tags: org-mode

Given this file:

```
#+title: test

some words.

/some emphasis/.

 /some emphasis/.

/emphasis/.
```

`org-export-as-latex` (emacs 23.4.1; Org-mode 6.33x) produces this:

```
[...]
some words.

\emph{some emphasis\}.

 \emph{some emphasis}.

\emph{emphasis}.
[...]
```

The compilation therefore fails.  The same is true if I use `*some emphasis*` where the markup is more than one word and and starts a new line.  Is this a known problem?

**Update:**

This seems to be a problem with emacs 23.4.1's org-mode (version 6.33x), at least as installed from the repositories for Ubuntu 12.10.  With emacs 24.1.1 (and 7.8.11), the problem disappears.  ... So this question is closed for me, but maybe there is still a solution for people still using emacs < 24.1.1

Comment: Org 6.33 ? You probably can upgrade that (last is 7.9-ish). Not a known problem that I know of.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks -- hmm, wait.  that's what it said from within org-mode.  But this is installed from the repositories for Ubuntu 12.10, which claims 7.8.11-2.... Need to investigate.  (Still a super-annoying problem for now!)

Comment: I read many cross-installations problems, this seems to be one. Maybe Org's [Installation page](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html) is of some help.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks -- thanks.  I was caught between the two versions because of my reliance on AUCTeX, which by default (in 12.10) is only set up for emacs23.  I changed that and reconfigured AUCTeX and now I'm using 24.1.1 across the board.  Thanks for the suggestions, though!